# Cannot find name 'bootstrap'

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

When I Want to add boot strap toast in angular Component
It says:
"Cannot find name 'bootstrap'"

HTML(Like BootstrapDocumentation):

```
<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
  </div>
</div>
```

angular ts file code:

```
      ngOnInit(): void {
    const toastTrigger = document.getElementById('liveToastBtn')
    const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')
    if (toastTrigger) {
      toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastLiveExample)

        toast.show()
      })
    }
  }
```

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx3FT.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can have a look at what's wrong. Based on the code you posted, it is impossible to tell where the problem is.

Comment: I added some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably didn't import or initialize `bootstrap` anywhere and it is not a global variable either, typescript compiler can not find it anywhere and hence the error. Import `Toast` directly from bootstrap and use it without bootstrap prefix:

```js
import { Toast } from 'bootstrap';
```

and then

```js
const toast = new Toast(toastLiveExample)
```

Most likely you will also have to install [@types/bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap)